# DISPLAY redirection in Visual Studio Code Remote - Containers on WSL2?

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, wsl-2

I'm trying to use VSCode with WSL 2 and Remote-Containers to develop inside the container but I'm unable to redirect the display for viewing the opencv / matplotlib images.

I have VcXsrv installed and used in combination with docker containers in PyCharm successfully and I'm trying to transfer the knowledge to be able to work directly in containers. However I had no luck in configuring the devcontainer.json in simmilar fasion:

I tried adding :

```
"runArgs": [
        "--net", "host", 
        "-e", "DISPLAY=X.X.X.X:0.0",
        "-v", "/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix"
]
```

to devcontainer.json, which feels wrong anyway.

I can eventually start the VSCode from MobaxTerm WSL which has its own X server, but I havent find the way to configure the container for that either.

Anybody has any experience ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end it is necessary to have vcxsrv configured with -a -c and "access control disabled". Then it is possible to

```
export DISPLAY=X.X.X.X:0.0
```

in VSCode bash terminal in the container.

That did the trick.